# Typescript strict-type checking not working with string and array in observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable

I am trying Typescript strict-type  checking and setting a return type of  function is a "string" but on success I am returning "resp.josn()" and its working even TS having strict-type checking.

Same issue with array like returning user[] but from response just passing object and that is working

Please help why its allowing this.

```
  public getInfo(): Observable<string> {
    const url = 'http://it-ebooks-apisss.info/v1/search/php%20mysql/page/3';
    var options = new RequestOptions({
       headers: new Headers({
       'Accept': 'application/text',
       })
    });
    return this.http.get(url, options).map((resp: Response) => (resp.json()))
}
```

Comment: In the provided example you are not returning a `string`, but `Observable<string>`- and this makes a difference. In the `return` line you are returning an observable so everything is ok with types.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianKaczmarek but  above we defining observable<string> and bellow returning observable<json> from return this.http.get() so  is that  ok

Answer (score 1):

Type checking works as expected.

If you check Angular's `Response` class, you'll see that `Response.json()` is defined as `() => any`, meaning that the `json` method can return ANY type. This is logical, as you never know what kind of object you can get when parsin JSON.

So, your `return` statement is performing the following type operations:

```
Observable<Response> -> (map) -> Observable<any>
```

Unfortunately, by using `any` in TypeScript you basically disable type checking. In TypeScript, `any` can be converted to and from anything. When using `any` you're telling TypeScript to mind its own bussiness because you know what you're doing.

So, `Observable<any>` can be assigned to a variable of type `Observable<string>`, and the other way around.

However, if you want to return text, maybe you shouldn't use `json()`, but `text()`. `text()` is `() => Observable<string>` and maybe is what you want.

Or you can tell `map` what type of object you're returning. If you know that `json()` returns an object that complies with `MyObject` inteface, then you can write:

```
return this.http.get(url, options).map((resp: Response) => <MyObject>(resp.json()));
```

And now the type conversion is:

```
Observable<Response> => (map) => Observable<MyObject>
```

And TypeScript will protest because your function is supposed to return `Observable<string>`.